# define logging in Silex

Tags: php, silex

If I define monolog logging in Silex:

```
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler;

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\MonologServiceProvider(), array(
    'monolog.name' => 'logger',
    'monolog.logfile' => $logdir . '/f2alma.log',
    'monolog.level' => \Monolog\Logger::DEBUG
));

$app['monolog']->addDebug('Testing the Monolog logging.');
...
$app->run();
```

I get the error PHP message:

> [Wed Jan 06 10:07:34.994088 2016] [:error] [pid 4594] [client
>   130.133.152.188:47369] PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 4 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::__construct()
>   must be an instance of Psr\Log\LoggerInterface, instance of
>   Monolog\Logger given, called in
>   /usr/local/silex/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Application.php on line
>   102 and defined in
>   /usr/local/silex/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php
>   on line 52

What's wrong here?

Thanks,

Christoph

Comment: Look in code if Monolog\Logger implements Psr\Log\LoggerInterface. May be monolog update will help..

Comment: Can you post your monolog and silex version?

Comment: Monolog: 1.0.2 (2011-10-24)
Silex: 1.3

Comment: problem is solved. The monolog version was too old ...

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I fixed it changing my monolog version.
The latest version can be checked at [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/monolog/monolog).